# XCTestCase - how to assert on a NSTextView containing String?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview, xctestcase, xcuitest

I have a macOS project that I'm creating UI tests for.

While it's relatively easy to find `staticText`, `buttons`, etc. by their text value.  Using a subscript lookup on `.textViews` doesn't (seem to) work.

I've managed to get a reference to the `NSTextView` I want to inspect using `.textViews.firstMatch` but I can't figure out how to assert on it's string value.

I'm looking for something that works like this.

```
XCTAssertEqual(prefs.textViews.firstMatch.stringValue, "Enter text below")
```

Comment: `textView.value as! String` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1501015-value) should do.
It's available on `XCUIElementAttributes` and is of type `Any?` that varies based on the type of the element.

```
XCTAssertEqual(prefs.textViews.firstMatch.value as! String, 
               "Enter text below")
```

---

Ref:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes

Comment: Very close, however `Any?` won't cast with `as? String`.  A force cast is needed. I've edited your answer with the modified casting.  Thank you though I've accepted your answer as it's _almost_ exactly what I needed.

Comment: @ocodo Glad to be of help :) And... thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you print out the `debugDescription` of the element, you should see which parameter holds the value you want to assert equality on. Likely it will be `.value` which you can simply coerce into a String for your purposes. Strings adhere to `==` equality checks, making it trivial to compare two strings with just a simple `XCTAssert(originalTextViewValue == "String I want to value check against")`

Comment: Effectively the same as the chosen answer. Thank you.  However, @staticVoidMan was more succinct and specific, and provided a cleanly formatted code example.